# Как определить строка пустая или нет с помощью length

Tags: java, android

Вроде задача простая, но не как не могу разобраться, как определить строка пустая или нет и указать это в switch case. Если пустая можно поставить просто 0, а если нет?

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);
int length = title.length;

switch (length) {
    case 0:
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp);
        break;

    case ???:
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну `default:`. Но вообще-то чем if-else не угодил?